# Reading and writing MS Project TimeScaleData for Resources, and Assignments

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am pulling projected cost into Excel reports and an external db. Part of the monthly projections are to update the project overheads. So I need to accurately pull monthly cost as well as write monthly cost to the overheads tasks.

I am having trouble understanding why would you read and write to an Assignment instead of directly to the cost Resource?

Read the month cost by resource (simplified):

```
Dim tsvs as TimeScaleValues
Dim res as Resource

Do Until budgetDate > ActiveProject.ProjectFinish
    For Each res In ActiveProject.Resources
        Set tsvs = res.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=budgetDate, EndDate:=budgetDate, Type:=pjResourceTimescaledCost, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleMonths, Count:=1)
        myMonthCost = Val(tsvs(1).Value)
    Next res
    budgetDate = DateAdd("m", budgetDate, 1)
Loop
```

There is only one TimeScaleValue in tsvs (the single month) so I believe that I'm fine just referencing tsvs(1).Value instead of having to increment through the collection.

Read month cost with assignments:

```
Do Until budgetDate > laborFinishDate
    For Each res In ActiveProject.Resources
        Set asgts = res.Assignments
        For Each asgt In asgts
            Set tsvs = asgt.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=budgetDate, EndDate:=budgetDate, Type:=pjAssignmentTimescaledCost, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleMonths, Count:=1)
            myMonthCost = myMonthCost + Val(tsvs(1).Value)
        Next asgt
    Next res
    budgetDate = DateAdd("m", budgetDate, 1)
Loop
```

And finally write the month overhead cost to the overhead task:

```
myOverhead = myMonthCost * myRate

Set tsk = ActiveProject.Tasks("Overhead")
Set tsvs = tsk.Assignments(1).TimeScaleData(StartDate:=budgetDate, EndDate:=budgetDate, Type:=pjAssignmentTimescaledCost, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleMonths)

tsvs(1).Value = myOverhead
```

This method works for me but I am frustrated I cannot get it to work writing directly to the resource cost. I don't really understand why I would have to read or write to an assignment (either task or resource) instead of directly to the resource itself. Could anyone explain why one should read and write costs using assignments or if there is a better way using the resources directly?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the assignments table contains the TimeScaleData that relates the resource to the task (and vice versa), so you must write to the assignment related to the resource (or task). Resource TimeScaleData is really the related Assignment TimeScaleData of the resource.